# Couchbase JSON structure model

Tags: php, database, json, couchbase

I want to work with couchbase json-document oriented.
But I don't know what's the best way to store and structure data and retrieve it later.

Is there somehow any tutorial to get started (the learing resources on couchbase.com did not help)?

I'm using PHP to access to couchbase.
I've got the following sample:

```
(new document)
user1
{
"uid":1,
"name":"marius"
}

(new document)
planet1
{
"pid":1,
"user_uid":1,
"name":"earth"
}

(new document)
user2
{
"uid":2,
"name":"anyone"
}

(new document)
planet2
{
"pid":2,
"user_uid":2,
"name":"saturn"
}
```

Now what would be the smartest way to set (insert) these documents into the database and how can I get (select) the documents by selection.

To say it in SQL I want to -> **SELECT * FROM user,planet WHERE user.uid=1 AND planet.user_uid=1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couchbase stores data differently than a relational database.

There are two main ways to get data out of Couchbase:

**Key/Value**. This means you give your document one key to query on and then obviously the value is going to be the entire document. So for a user:

```
user = couch.get(123)
```

That would return the entire document for user ID 123.

**Views**. You can write views in Couchbase using map/reduce functions. The cool thing is that these views can be accessed in a similar way to views in CouchDB, so you can do things like ordering and limiting.  http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options

Check out the design documents/views in your Couchbase portal. When you write one it'll give you a URL to test your map/reduce stuff. Then you can add parameters to the URL to do additional work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way in saying how your documents should be designed. It do depend on the characteristics of your app. Write vs Read ratio? How is the data consumed etc. With the strengths of transforming data using views in couch, I guess you could make more "generic" documents and create specific views that transform the doc to fit your use-case. Of course not a solution that you should apply to all use-cases (don't see it as the silver-bullet design).

A classic example is the blog example. Should you store comments in the post or extract comments and have the reside on their own, with a reference? It depends on the characteristics. Is it more common to have a few comments or is it usually loads of comments?

Another sample. What if you store a order document. Should the customer be part of the order or the order of the customer? Could it be both? Yes, it could. I would say that with document dbs you need to be a bit more open to duplication of data. Could it be that the Customer doc still exists as the "current view" of the customer, with all his data and the Order contains fragments of a customer snapshot; useful for the order-context and some overview in the app, which then uses references to the actual customer doc? Probably. But again, it depends on how you would consume the data.

Regarding SQL translation: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-writing-sql.html